# Passing a 2d string table to webservice method

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, web-services, asmx

My web service takes string [][] as a parameter, but when I call webservice method it gives error:

> cannot convert from 'string[][]' to 'ServiceReference1.ArrayOfString[]

```
//strItems1 is the array
string [][] strItems1 = new string[m_Inputs][];
for (int i =0; i < m_Inputs; i++)
    strItems1[i] = new string[2];

for (int i =0; i < m_Inputs; i++)
{
    strItems1[i][0] = "test";
    strItems1[i][1] = "test 1";
}
oS.CostFromStringArray(strItems1, oDB.EscapeString(STZ.Text), Total); //web service method on which i am getting error
```

It's just a string table that is always going to be string[n][2], i also tried using multi-dimensional arrays but wsdl gave error that use jagged arrays instead.

Comment: Regarding error message you need `ServiceReference1.ArrayOfString[]` rather that `string[][]`

Comment: looking at it it looks like your parameter is just a string array, could you post more code like your web method

Comment: Is it possible that the dimensions of the array are reversed? Perhaps the web service is expecting the data as string[2][n]?

Comment: Is this a WCF service, or ASMX?

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice i made the web service, its string [][] in WebMethod signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web Service type was of data type array, used a `list<>` and before passing it in to web service method do a `list<>.ToArray(`) for soap to be able to serialize it.
You can also change the web service data type. `Right Click on service refrence > Configure Service > Data Type Fields`